# Ping windows machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

Originally I wanted to access the Tomcat Web Server from another machine in the LAN. Since it didn't worked I tried `ping` command. However, I get timeouts when the Windows firewall is on. My machine is reachable when I turn it off. I already enabled the Inbound rules for File and Printer sharing. But even with a general allowance for incoming connections nothing changed. After all I resetted the firewall settings to default and started again.

Any ideas what I can try to make my PC reachable?

Comment: I think, you must create firewall ICMP rules INBOUND and OUTBOUND

Comment: Windows firewall has those rules by default but they are deactivated. Activating them doesn't help. Creating my own rules either.

Comment: Do not use `ping` to troubleshoot anything. This is useless. If you need to test access to your web server... do an HTTP(S) query and see if you get any reply. Bonus: you do not have specific rules in your firewall just the ones needed by your webserver.